# Azure DevOps Personal Access Token

Tags: python, azure-devops, oauth-2.0

I have my PAT and some example code to pull the projects within my organization. However when I try to use a `GET` command to read a work item I am given `response 203`. Most of my Googling has lead to three solutions, neither of which has been successful for me. One mentions editing my PAT using base64 and a `:`. The second says to use an oauth2 python library. The third solution is the code below.

```
PE_DEVOPS_NAME = "DevOpsArea"

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = ':XXXX'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/'

post_url = organization_url + PE_DEVOPS_NAME + "/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0"
get_url = organization_url + PE_DEVOPS_NAME + "/_apis/wit/workitems/60814?api-version=6.0"

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

# Get the first page of projects
get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()

for project in get_projects_response.value:
    if project.name == PE_DEVOPS_NAME:
        print(project.name)

response = requests.get(get_url)
print(get_url)
print(response.json)
```

Am I missing something in the above code that would make my PAT not work?

I kept looking and found the following code:

```
username = ''
personal_access_token = 'XXXX'
login_info = username + ":" + personal_access_token
b64 = base64.b64encode(login_info.encode()).decode()
headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic %s" % b64}


organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/'

post_url = organization_url + PE_DEVOPS_NAME + "/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0"
get_url = organization_url + PE_DEVOPS_NAME + "/_apis/wit/workitems/60814?api-version=6.0"

response = requests.get(get_url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

This code works for my `GET` command. I will test with a `POST`. Can anyone explain why this works but the azure python library does not?

Comment: I'm using the PAT as a password, without specifying a username.  So, the auth is `:MYPATHERE` then encoded as base64; note the leading colon to specify the PAT as a password.

Comment: If I perform `base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8'))` to encode my PAT and remove the username I am given an error that the user '' is not authorized access to the resource.

Comment: I think the full `username:password` string needs to be base64 encoded, but I would not encode the password alone.  Just set the username to be a blank string, and try again?

Comment: My username is now empty and I added a : to the PAT. Performed the base64 and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For the first sample in your code, definitely it will not work, there are two errors in your code.

1. When you use `response = requests.get(get_url)`, it does not use any credential to call the REST API.
2. Even you use the [`Azure DevOps Python API`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) python library, it should be `personal_access_token = 'XXXX'` instead of `personal_access_token = ':XXXX'`, you should not include `:` character.
3. For `203` status code, if you use `print(response.text)` instead of `print(response.json)` in the last line, easily you can find it just returns a sign-in page.

   [image]

To get the work item with the [`Azure DevOps Python API`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) python library, you could add the code below to your sample, it gets the work item whose `id` is `68`, if you want to get the `60814` one, just use `range(60814, 60815)`.

```
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
desired_ids = range(68, 69)
print(desired_ids)
work_items = wit_client.get_work_items(ids=desired_ids)
for wit in work_items:
    print(wit)
```

[image]

Reference - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-samples/blob/552544e9cde70269e37784aff2e62dd97420b862/src/samples/work_item_tracking.py

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to the ADO API using Microsoft python client https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api (version 7.1.0b4) and using requests package. Please see the code below that has worked for me. You will need to add some checks to make it bulletproof of course.

```
import requests
import base64
import json
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

personal_access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
organization = 'YOUR_ORGANIZATION'
organization_url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}'

#method 1    
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()
for project in get_projects_response:
    print(project.id, project.name)

#method 2
authorization = str(
    base64.b64encode(bytes(":" + personal_access_token, "ascii")), "ascii"
)

projects_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic " + authorization}

response = requests.get(url=projects_url, headers=headers)
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
print(response_dict['value'][0]['id'], response_dict['value'][0]['name'])
```